# Git checkout issues HEAD -> master

Tags: node.js, git, express, github

```
89499ab (HEAD -> current-branch, temp-branch, current1-branch) Insertion of README.mg
ecb2fc9 validation of user operation on the UI
88417e7 add some files to .gitignore
f9f24e1 Integration of nodemailer
8c8b0f4 Express-Validator
64b80ff Express Server Integration
a2267ce (origin/master, master) First Project Commit
```

hello, i am no expert in git. i did a git checkout sometime age and my problem started from there. i tried to push my local git online but the "origin/master, master" is still on my first commit of "a22567ce" but it should be on the last commit of "89499ab"

infact it should look like this below

```
89499ab (HEAD -> master, origin/master) Insertion of README.mg
ecb2fc9 validation of user operation on the UI
88417e7 add some files to .gitignore
f9f24e1 Integration of nodemailer
8c8b0f4 Express-Validator
64b80ff Express Server Integration
a2267ce First Project Commit
```

Also, how do i remove the branches i have created >> current-branch, temp-branch, current1-branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you did is right! If you are ready to move `master` forward, then `git checkout master`, `git merge current-branch`, and `git push`.

You can then delete your branches with `git branch -d current-branch` and so on. If any of them refuses to delete, git will tell you what to say.

Comment: Yay! But remember, the most important thing is that what you did is perfectly correct. Not a problem. Making your commits on a secondary branch is _normal_.